# Forwarding spam from gmail to email gateway for anti-spam testing

Tags: spam, spam-filter, mail-forwarding

Is it possible to forward all emails that end up in my gmail spam folder to another email address?  We're standing up a new anti-spam email gateway and need to generate some real email for testing what gets through vs. what gets quarantined.

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/550341/disable-gmails-spam-filter-when-forwarding-email

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do that.** Mail that already got processed by a third party (Google) is not "real email". Although the content (body) is considered as Spam, the header is manipulated. By forwarding the mail it gets worse:
Your anti-spam solution gets trained that all Spam comes from Google. Which is wrong.

If it is an off-the-shelf solution, then you can just trust it. Real mail (not forwarded!!) will train the system. Let it just go.

By the way: If you have a solution that quarantines mail then this is the wrong solution. An anti-spam solution has to REJECT (not bounce) Spam.